# Piedra, papel o tijera en C

Tags: c

He elaborado un programa para el siguiente problema:

Simule el tradicional juego de piedra, papel o tijera utilizando las estructuras de control selectivas.
Incluya la librería time.h y stdlib.h además del comando srand.

En este juego de azar participan dos personas buscando un ganador. Las reglas son las siguientes:

-Tijera corta papel-Papel envuelve a piedra-Piedra rompe tijera-Si elijen el mismo es empate-Con cualquier opción diferente el usuario pierde

**Sólo quiero saber si es posible hacer una mejora a mi código en cuanto a estilo o al algoritmo que empleé para resolverlo:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int seleccionUsuario;           //El usuario y la computadora elijen entre piedra, papel o tijeras
    double seleccionComputadora;

    printf("************PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA************\n\n");


    do{
        printf("Selecciona una opcion: 1.-Piedra   2.-Papel    3.-Tijera    ");
        scanf("%i", &seleccionUsuario);

        switch(seleccionUsuario){
        case 1: printf("\n¡Haz seleccionado Piedra!\n");
        break;
        case 2: printf("\n¡Haz seleccionado Papel!\n");
        break;
        case 3: printf("\n¡Haz seleccionado Tijeras!\n");
        break;
        default: printf("\nSolo puedes seleccionar un numero entre 1 y 3\n\n");
        break;
        }//fin switch
    }while(seleccionUsuario>3||seleccionUsuario<1); //Delimitamos a 3 las opciones del usuario

    //Hacemos que la computadora elija un número aleatorio entre uno y tres
    srand(time(NULL));
    seleccionComputadora= (rand()%2)+1;

    if(seleccionComputadora==1)
        printf("\n¡Tu ordenador ha seleccionado Piedra!\n");
    else if(seleccionComputadora==2)
        printf("\n¡Tu ordenador ha seleccionado Papel!\n");
    else if(seleccionComputadora==3)
        printf("\n¡Tu ordenador ha seleccionado Tijera!\n");

    //Determinamos al ganador de la contienda
    if(seleccionUsuario==2&&seleccionComputadora==1)
        printf("\nGanaste\n");
    else if(seleccionUsuario==3&&seleccionComputadora==2)
        printf("\nGanaste\n");
    else if(seleccionUsuario==1&&seleccionComputadora==3)
        printf("\nGanaste\n");
    else if(seleccionUsuario==seleccionComputadora)
        printf("\nEmpate\n");
    else
        printf("\nPerdiste\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En todas las estructuras condicionales te faltaron los corchetes ({}).

Comment: Los corchetes son opcionales si la instrucción es una sola línea; pero se considera buena práctica añadirlas incluso en ese caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sólo quiero saber si es posible hacer una mejora a mi código.

Eso es en muchos casos subjetivo e irrelevante en casos de código tan corto. Personalmente, la mejora que puedes hacer a tu código es acortarlo para hacer que sea más fácil de entender y mantener.

Empieza por crear un enumerado con los valores posibles del juego:

```
enum Jugada { Piedra, Papel, Tijera };
```

Añade una función que traduzca jugada a texto:

```
void ImprimeJugada(enum Jugada jugada)
{
    switch (jugada)
    {
        case Piedra: printf("Piedra"); break;
        case Papel: printf("Papel"); break;
        case Tijera: printf("Tijera"); break;
    };
}
```

Sigue con una formación<sup>1</sup> que empareje cada jugada con la que la derrota:

```
enum Jugada contrajugada[] = { Papel, Tijera, Piedra };
```

Con estos sencillos cambios, el inicio de tu programa se reduce a pocas líneas:

```
printf("************PIEDRA, PAPEL O TIJERA************\n\n");

do {
    printf("Selecciona una opcion: 1.-Piedra   2.-Papel    3.-Tijera    ");
    scanf("%i", &seleccionUsuario);
} while(seleccionUsuario > 3 || seleccionUsuario < 1);

printf("\n¡Has seleccionado "); // El presente de indicativo del verbo 'Haber' es 'Has', no 'Haz'.
ImprimeJugada((enum Jugada)seleccionUsuario - 1);
printf("!\n");
```

También se acorta el código de la selección del ordenador:

```
/* Debes hacer módulo sobre 3 para tener 3 valores diferentes, si haces módulo
   sobre 2 tendrás dos valores. */
seleccionComputadora = (rand() % 3);
printf("\n¡Tu ordenador ha seleccionado ");
ImprimeJugada((enum Jugada)seleccionComputadora);
printf("!\n");
```

Y determinar el resultado de la contienda es trivial:

```
if (contrajugada[seleccionUsuario - 1] == seleccionComputadora)
{
    printf("\nPerdiste\n");
}
else if (contrajugada[seleccionComputadora] == (seleccionUsuario - 1))
{
    printf("\nGanaste\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\nEmpate\n");
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVPLbtswEDyLX7FxkYIqZKOOb3ESwGiN1oHRCKlzinvYiEzMVCIFSmoOiT@mv5Ifc0g9YspSLyUggLsczsyultEwilE@7HYfhIzignE4y3Im1GhzQVqpWNy1c7lIuM0QLosELosHZAjPEArONAYQYsrjAFbikWuE7bQFi5TMNT6Wwe0vOLf3XHxQ09h75I8SDBZJqo1gdZ@6XBWLT56Jlz2JPNoAbVKeyXkRZrymOwVDIvN7OqjigT@FO83x9/QdZ104MBt2UZXJPayKXZzxvSXEnEKCQlJbQunQZjIe8ygSSt5kBWqhgn3mi0rSIkemNJrCvYb/k7PCxfzr9cw0aBbOl3AFq8Xl/HrmItZyLY0Xc58psB1oaH42MgiF@VRq96cwHg3rbgOcmL2t2WxhMhrWf88sS@h5WYTSEB2LQQAfD@uwiC08bUTM6eEZXMAEXl46tcMZjH231LV8/fsdsz3QNKMSb0@AOwJ@h3VYsr6THjUNyTRKRu3k0h83y6VvQX3NNxNJS6gPxzBxqay/VQFKM26tadjgf3p15Hq9inugrXfSV6V5O@e941MP/952yDUTWc4rem9LPB6bUf63ikNWqtDeLnd0vqHEjswhaJ6k6GCIp3leaAmfzbPZ7cbkDQ)</kbd>.

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Añadiría también una función que haga explícito el paso de entero a enumerado, aunque haya una relación directa subyacente, o bien asignar valores literales al enumerado para que dicha correlación entre enumerado y valor entero sea explícita, ya que en un nivel de aprendizaje básico resulta confusa esa transformación de entero a enumerado para restarle 1: `(enum Jugada)seleeccionUsuario - 1`.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez la transformación de entero a enumerado es explícita por dos motivos: 1) `enum Jugada` no es `int`, ergo hay que hacer la conversión. 2) explicitar la transformación denota la intencionalidad del programador, es decir: denota que es una conversión deliberada, no accidental. Restar 1 a `seleccionUsuario` es porque la indización original está un valor por encima del valor enumerado (al contrario que en `seleccionComputadora`).

Comment: Quizá me he expresado mal. Me refería a hacer explícita la relación entre un valor entero y un valor enumerado concreto, no tanto al casting. Como por ejemplo que `Papel` se corresponde con el 0. Por supuesto que no es necesario ponerla, y menos para cualquier programador con algo de experiencia.